# BizTalk - WSE 3.0 Adapter

Tags: biztalk, wse3.0

We need to consume a web service  (which is a WSE3.0 service) using BizTalk 2010. I did some initial research and WSE is not supported out of the box.

From what I can tell, the only thing I found is that there is a company called Two Connect (who are BizTalk consultants) that did it according to this post:

[http://geekswithblogs.net/dnoderer/archive/2006/05/09/77731.aspx]

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to implement it? A blog, article, etc.? Or is there a product we can purchase.

Thanks!
G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit late, but here you go: http://fafach.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/biztalk-2010-converting-wse-send-port-to-wcf/